# How to Calculate Conditional Average (Volume Weighted) by TimeDate Group in R?

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

I am trying to calculate volume weighted average price (VWAP) from a trade data, based on same DateTime group. The sample data from a small data frame (20,000 entries) is as following:

```
testdata[,c(5,8,10,11)]
               transactiontime price volume totalEquity
334 2014-12-01 01:30:00.110000 19330 500000      966500
335 2014-12-01 01:30:00.830000 19340   8000       15472
336 2014-12-01 01:30:00.830000 19340   1000        1934
337 2014-12-01 01:30:00.830000 19340   1000        1934
338        2014-12-01 01:30:01 19340    500         967
339        2014-12-01 01:30:01 19340   2000        3868
340        2014-12-01 01:30:01 19340   4000        7736
341        2014-12-01 01:30:01 19340  40000       77360
342        2014-12-01 01:30:01 19340 500000      967000
343        2014-12-01 01:30:01 19340  12000       23208
```

where `totalEquity` was an added column by `workdata$totalEquity <- (workdata$price)/10000 * (workdata$volume)`

I want to calculate VWAP by transaction time. Using `aggregate` is easy to calculate `mean(totalEquity)`, but how can I calculate the volume weighted average so to achieve something like:

```
group.1            transactiontime weightedPrice
1       2014-12-01 01:30:00.110000         1.933
2       2014-12-01 01:30:00.830000         1.934
3              2014-12-01 01:30:01         1.934
```

where `weightedPrice` is `sum(totalEquity)/sum(volume)`, grouped by `transactiontime`.

I've searched for many questions on group mean but did not know how to combine each function correctly; none of my previous attempts worked, as of following,  and I was very frustrated:

```
volWeighted <- function(x=workdata$totalEquity,y=workdata$volume) {sum(x)/sum(y)}
aggregate(totalEquity~transactiontime, testdata, FUN=volWeighted)
```

or

```
library(data.table)
dt[,list(avg_tte <- sum(testdata$totalEquity)/sum(testdata$volume)),
'testdata$transactiontime']
```

or

```
setDT(testdata) [, time.diff :=max(time)-min(time), by=transactiontime]
                [, if(time.diff==0)
                      .( totalEquity = sum(totalEquity)/sum(volume))
                    else .SD, by = .(transactiontime, time.diff)]
```

This is my first question and I tried to make it efficient, but if it happens to be a duplicate, please let me know and I am very willing to learn from the previous question.

Comment: Try `setDT(testdata) [, list(avg_tte = sum(totalEquity)/sum(volume)), transactiontime]`

Comment: there is a `weighted.mean`, `sapply(split(testdata, testdata$transactiontime), function(x) weighted.mean(x$price, x$volume))`

Comment: Thanks! Both arguments worked. @ExperimenteR suits my need better for running faster and the result yields to a data table+frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close on all your attempts.

Instead of `aggregate` try `by`:

```
by(workdata, workdata$transactiontime, function (x) sum(x$totalEquity)/sum(x$volume))
```

This will return just the values in of the `weightedPrice` column - up to you to add it to the dataframe.

I'd recommend something like `plyr` or `data.frame`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(workdata, .(transactiontime), summarize,
      weightedPrice=sum(totalEquity)/sum(volume))
```

The `summarize` function calculates some summary statistic, and `ddply` calls `summarize` for each unique `transactiontime`. The calculation works a bit like the `transform` function, where if you write `weightedPrice=sum(totalEquity)/sum(volume)` it calculates the expression looking up columns in `workdata` (so no need for `workdata$columnname`), and assigns it to a column called `weightedPrice`.

If `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(workdata) # turn workdata into data.table
workdata[, list(weightedPrice=sum(totalEquity)/sum(volume)), by=transactiontime]
```

Comment: I went through the steps you provided and they were really helpful. Thanks for the detailed teaching! Much appreciation! :)